# Add margin to glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I simply want to add some additional righthand margin to the bootstrap glyphicons in an *a*-tag, but it won't work out. The menu looks as follows:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i>Choose project...<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
             </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="#" class="btn-file">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
              Open layer...<input type="file">
           </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

And the css I am trying to use is:

```
a > .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

The menu looks fine, when setting the margin in the inline style and even when live-editing the site (using MagiCSS), the selector works properly. But when loading it from file, it has no effect (I checked if I am editing the proper .css-file and reloaded the browser cache already)..

Does anybody see something here? Could this be because of some bootstrap styles the glyphs inherit?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.
Kim

**Solved**
Thanks Paulie_D for the tip. I could not reproduce this in JSFiddle either, but adding

```
i { display: inline-block; }
```

did the trick on my local copy!

Comment: try using !important on your css margin property and see if works

Comment: Is the `<i>` set to `display:inline-block`? Cannot reproduce - http://jsfiddle.net/uooL47ez/

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
a > .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 6px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the '!important' annotation. Unfortunately it did not change anything :-(

Comment: place you custom.css file after bootstrap.css file in the head